# how to work with asp.net mvc project that's have only one user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, logging

I am working on a project to be used in a company. The system will have **only 1 administrator account.**

The administrator will add system users and each user can create his own contacts.

I created a WCF service to connect with the database, an asp.net mvc3 project for admin, and another WPF app for system users.

My questions is:

> I have only one user (admin) to log in with this asp.net mvc project:
>   how do I work with this situation?

I think membership provider and database are not required because I am only working with one user, right??

Comment: You'll get better answers if you provide code samples.

Comment: @robrich why you need code for this questions ?

Comment: If You really need only one admin account You could hardcode username and password in web.config (authentication node) and then create some admin controller that will handle login to admin store using FormsAuthentication class. That way You wont need a database, but I still would rather use Membership and Role Provider. It's safer that way.

Comment: thanks @lucask that's what i need but how i can make all pages in my mvc project work only with this user

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

**web.config**:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Admin/LogOn" timeout="2880" >
    <credentials passwordFormat="SHA1">
      <user name="admin" password="5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8"/>
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Password format is set to SHA1, so Your password won't be visible in clear text. It still can be cracked though. Generate Your own hash using online SHA1 generator for example.

loginUrl is a route to Your login page (duh :P), so change it if it's different.

**CredentialsViewModel**:

```
public class CredentialsViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

View model for Your login view.

**AdminController**:

```
public ViewResult LogOn()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(CredentialsViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
            return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Admin"));                
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username or password");
        }
    }

    return View();
}

[Authorize]
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

So LogOn action will authenticate credentials passed from the view; compare it with web.config data.

Important part here is [[Authorize]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) attribute which will prevent access from unauthorized users.

Comment: Works great for more than one user as well, as long as those users' credentials are set in stone and there aren't too many. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely need a User table to handle non-Admin accounts.  It would be trivial to add the Admin user to this table as well, and add a column labeled "IsAdmin" where only that one is set to true.  Membership and Role providers can do this nicely, and may be faster to build what you need, though they tend to barf all over your database.

.. as a side-note, though you're quite confident there will only ever be one Admin account, I suspect that requirement will change eventually, and probably without notice.